# How to impliment search in openerp web framework

Tags: odoo, web-frameworks

I created a module which displays filenames,size,time created etc of files in a directory . I showed this in table using openerp web framework. now i want search and group by options for this data. How can i achive this? I am not saving any data in db. Any one please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Well Anuradha,

I see that you have done the thing purely using the web (qWeb) so you will be needing separate widget to enable the search facility over your view, similler example can be found on chatter wall i.e. messaging menu.

Thank You